# ucharclasses not working with Devanagari text

Tags: ucharclasses

Check this code:

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\s[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari} % Or any other Devanagari font
\usepackage[Devanagari,Latin]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{Devanagari}{\s}
\setTransitionFrom{Devanagari}{\rmfamily}
\setTransitionsForDevanagari{\s}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
English देवनागरी English देवनागरी   ॥१॥ % last character is not appearing.
\end{document}
```

This is yielding this output. [image].
Where this punction sign (॥) double danda is not appearing after devanagari digit 1 at the end. How to handle this?

Comment: You get `Missing character: There is no ॥ (U+0965) in font [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!`  so it's switched back to latin too early

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I find it's often easier to use the character class commands directly rather than via the `ucharclasses` interface, but anyway for reasons that are not clear it is switching to the roman font before the character so you get

```
Missing character: There is no ॥ (U+0965) in font
     [lmroman10-regular]:mapping=tex-text;!
```

The commented out `\showthe` confirms the ॥ is class 3 which the log shows is

```
\DevanagariDanDaClass=\XeTeXcharclass3
```

So I just added another line to assert that the Devanagari font  should be used for this class (it ought to be covered by the Devanagari meta class, but clearly that's not worked).

```
\documentclass[crop]{standalone}
% \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\s[Script=Devanagari]{Noto Serif Devanagari} % Or any other Devanagari font
\usepackage[Devanagari,Latin]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{Devanagari}{\s}
\setTransitionFrom{Devanagari}{\rmfamily}
\setTransitionsForDevanagari{\s}{\rmfamily}
\setTransitionTo{DevanagariDanDa}{\s}%<<<< added

%\showthe\XeTeXcharclass"0965
%\showthe\XeTeXcharclass`१
%\showthe\XeTeXcharclass`॥
\begin{document}
English देवनागरी English देवनागरी   ॥१॥ % last character is not appearing.
\end{document}
```